# Moviepy: How to concatenate moviepy composite video clips?

Tags: python, for-loop, video-processing, moviepy

I am working on looping through a nest of my home camera videos and concatenating videos. I want to have a program that I can run periodically to organize my videos. The directory structure of my memory card is as follows:

```
/day
--/hour
---00.mp4
---01.mp4
...
```

My strategy has been to define `getHour` function that combines all the minute files in a given directory with concatenation returning an object that can be written. This functions without issue as in I can write any hour. However when I try to run this in a loop to combine hours the object that I return is a composite video class which I can't concatenate in the same way, how do I concatenate a list of these objects?

```
# import moviepy
import moviepy.editor as mp
import os

# combine all the minutes in an hour
def getHour(hour_directory):
    print(hour_directory)
    os.chdir(hour_directory)
    minutes = os.listdir(hour_directory)
    clips = []
    for minute in minutes[0:3]:
        if minute.endswith(".mp4"):
                clips.append(mp.VideoFileClip(minute))
    video = mp.concatenate_videoclips(clips, method='compose')
    return video

# loop through 3 hours lets say and combine the results for each hour into one big clip
hours = ['00', '01', '02']
day_clips = []
day_direc = "~/20220301"
for hour in hours:
    hr = getHour(day_direc + "/" + hour)
    #day_clips.append(mp.VideoFileClip(hr)) # this requires an actual video
    day_clips.append(hr) # clearly not the right approach
    del(hr)

print(day_clips)
day_clips.write_videofile('newVideo.mp4')
del(day_clips)
```

Looking at the results of day_clips I can see the objects are moviePy classes:

```
<moviepy.video.compositing.CompositeVideoClip.CompositeVideoClip object at 0x7fcc9025e760>, <moviepy.video.compositing.CompositeVideoClip.CompositeVideoClip object at 0x7fcca079f370>, <moviepy.video.compositing.CompositeVideoClip.CompositeVideoClip object at 0x7fcca07a61f0>]
```

There must be a way to combine these? Or is my general approach incorrect?